# Line Drawing Game Help Tutorial for iPhone

Tags: iphone

I am looking for anyone that can help create some source and a tutorial with me to answer how to create a game like "air control" or "harbor patrol" - just a simple source file where a user can draw using their finger and an object will follow - no need for final collision detection just the simple follow path source.

Thanks
Matthew

PS If anyone knows of a tutorial already out there please point it out I do not want to reinvent the wheel, I would like to screen capture the tutorial and post it for others when finished. Anyone who helps will get attribution and a link to their sites.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here](http://www.stanford.edu/class/cs193p/downloads/05-Stalker.zip)'s a sample app from the [Stanford iPhone Programming Course](http://www.stanford.edu/class/cs193p/cgi-bin/index.php) that does something similar to what you want.

Comment: Thanks so much - close close getting there - this code example is great would you know how to change it so if I draw a path the red box will follow the path my finger draws?

Comment: I'm not at my Mac right now, so I can't test, but I guess that if you remove the animation it will follow your finger straight away.

Answer (score 2):

If you're still looking, check out this [line-drawing game starterkit](http://www.binpress.com/app/linedrawing-game-starterkit/551) over at [Binpress](http://www.binpress.com)

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [MoveMe.app](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/Creating_an_iPhone_App/index.html) from the SDK examples

Comment: Thank you so much - not sure how I missed this one but definitely helpful - do you know of any apps or tutorials that will have a graphic follow the exact path your finger makes on the screen by chance this is the best way  to describe exactly what I am looking for.